# Encoding issue with neo4 batch-importer tool

Tags: neo4j

I am new in neo4j and graph databases.

I am trying to import some test nodes and edges by using Michael Hunger's jexp / batch-import open source Github project. As I understand from documentation putting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 line into batc.properties file should be enough but unfortunately it does not work.

i am running tool as below. (Because my server does not have internet access, I can not use mvn )

```
./import.sh /neo4j/data/graph.db /nodes.txt /rels.txt
```

What I am missing?

```
[root@localhost batch_importer_20]# vi batch.properties 

batch_import.mapdb_cache.disable=true
cache_type=none
batch_import.keep_db=true
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=400M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=6G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=15M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=15M
```

Comment: Are your csv files in UTF-8?

Comment: yes its UTF-8. do you have any idea about the resason?

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting? Wrong property names/values or some exception?

Comment: I dont get exception. After loading nodes, neo4j browser does not display special charcters like çşü. When i create node over browser with cypher script it displays correct. It is probably about batch importer missing or wrong config settings

Comment: any chance to share a snippit of the files?

Comment: the file is very simple. id\tname\tsex 

i:id   name sex l:label
109214838 ANIL IŞILAK M Person
109715876 METİN ERKAN M Person
103611084 GÖRKEM GÖKDUMAN M Person
101208684 MEHMET HAKAN ŞAHİN M Person

Comment: I thought `-D` was for setting properties as options on the command line, not in a properties file. What happens if you remove it so the line reads `file.encoding=UTF-8`?

Comment: the import.sh already uses -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 any chance to upload a sample of your files for testing?

Comment: You file example seems to be messed up. Once you have tab delimiters and then space??

Comment: Hi Michael, I couldnt find any link to attach my sample csv file in here. The format of csv is ok. it works. i am getting the export from database in a windows environment. than i copy yhe file into linux server. when i chekck gile with linux more or vi command i see the all characters correctly. bu after importing data into with your tool , i can not see non-english chars on neo4j browser.

Comment: [root@localhost conf]# more neo4j-wrapper.conf 
    wrapper.java.additional=-    Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
    wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
    wrapper.java.additional=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties
    wrapper.java.additional=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Dear Michael Hunger, do you have any idea about my non english characters problem? It is critical issue for my graph project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your .csv is in UTF-8.
Use notepad++ to convert it in 'UTF-8 without BOM', then save.